# Good Text Editor With Macros

Tags: gedit, text-editor

Do you know of a usable text editor with monospace font and support for macros?

On Windows, I used to use notepad++ which was great. It's Linux equivalent nqq doesn't have macro support.

I tried installing [this plugin](https://github.com/eguaio/gedit-macropy) to Gedit, but it doesn't seem to work.

Running notepad++ under Wine doesn't work for me either, because in this case, the editor font is not monospaced for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at **`geany`**, that you can install from the repository universe

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install geany
```

You find information about macros for `geany` by searching the internet for **geany macro**.

Comment: Do not forget about [Plugins](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=hirsute&section=all&arch=any&keywords=geany-plugin&searchon=names) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

- vi
- vim.tiny
- vim
- gvim

I also had trouble getting the macro plugin to work with gedit.  I haven't given up yet, but it was taking too long to be worth it today.

Answer (score 0):

These are pretty useful.

- VS Code
- Sublime Text

If you are looking for an Integrated Development Environment (IDE), then you have other choices.

Write back and tell us what kind of editing you'll need to do.

Comment: I just need a light weight text editor, where I can open a plain text file, record a macro (series of key presses) and run it multiple times. I actually use VS Code but didn't realize it had macros. Is that some plugin? Can you specify which one?

Comment: Check the visual studio marketplace.  True confession: I haven't used VS Code for more than 20 minutes, and that was 2 years ago on Windows.  Still, it's worth exploring, and chances are you'd get lots of support from StackExchange and its forums.

Answer (score -1):

Jesus, I am writing my answere again. This AskUbuntu form is not working correctly. Please, tell the developers.

**Sublime** in my opinion is the best. You don't have to install any extra lib or package or plugin or module or etc.